# SOQL query for attachment body never contains the expected data

Tags: soql, api, attachment

Salesforce's [developer documentation for the attachment object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_attachment.htm) says (at the bottom of the page, emphasis mine):

> However, you can't receive the Body field for **multiple** records in a single query() call. If your query returns the Body field, your client application must **ensure that only one row with one Attachment is returned**; otherwise, an error occurs.

Consider the following query:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Body FROM Attachment WHERE Id = '00Pp000000BH3TJEA1' LIMIT 1
```

The query executes without error and returns the correct record with the correct name etc. Unfortunately, the Body field only contains this:

```
{/services/data/v36.0/sobjects/Attachment/00Pp000000BH3TJEA1/Body}
```

I was expecting a base64-encoded attachment body, but instead just get a URL which I'm sure I could pass into the REST API to get what I want, but we aren't using the REST API, and I can reproduce this behaviour everywhere I can run SOQL queries, whether it's the CLI, the C# client library and even the developer console, both in a sandbox and our production environment, and for any attachment, using a system admin account.

I'm selecting a single attachment by ID as well as using "LIMIT 1", and this query definitely returns only one record.  What am I doing incorrectly that is preventing the actual attachment Body from being included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at the SOAP API documentation. To get a file's content in the REST API, you always use the URL as you've seen it. This is documented in [sObject Blob Retrieve](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_blob_retrieve.htm) and [Get Attachment Content from a Record](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_blob_retrieve.htm).

Comment: Gah, it even says "SOAP API Documentation" right there at the top of the page.  Ouch.  We're actually using the DeveloperForce C# client library which doesn't seem to have any way to query attachment contents, so I guess we'll have to go back to using the REST API directly :(